# Authentication and authorization in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

When we using asp.net membership provider we can easily restrict pages from anonymous user by adding in web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
       <system.web>
         <authorization>
          <allow roles="Manager,Admin" />
          <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

in my application i don't use asp.net membership authentication and i have my own tables with custom structure.
also i have my User, Roles and UserInRoles Tables. i want to enable this mechanism in my application

any ideas?

Comment: I really do not understand what you asking.

Comment: Are you looking for "Create a Custom Membership Provider"?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following:

[Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)

[Implementing a Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx)

[Implementing a Profile Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0580x1f5%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[[How Do I:] Create a Custom Membership Provider?](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-189.aspx) (Video)

[[How Do I:] Create a Custom Profile Provider?](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-190.aspx) (Video)